# Filter pipe after more fields in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, filter

[I have this snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wl6rww) that filters a list after more field.

If I check `john` and `mike` it will result:

> 0 - john, g1
>
> 1 - mike, g2

But if I check `john`, `mike` and `g3` (which does not belong to any of these 2 users), because of pipe, it will search for `g3` but there is no result:

> 

How can I modify the code, if I check `g3` not to result `null`, but remain the current filtered list?

Thank you for your time!

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  users = [
    { 'id': '0', 'name': 'john', 'group': 'g1' },
    { 'id': '1', 'name': 'mike', 'group': 'g2' },
    { 'id': '2', 'name': 'anne', 'group': 'g3' },
    { 'id': '3', 'name': 'dan', 'group': 'g1' },
    { 'id': '4', 'name': 'zoe', 'group': 'g2' },
  ]
  groupValue: string[] = []
  userValue: string[] = []

  changeGroup(event) {
    const group = event.target.value;
    const index = this.groupValue.indexOf(group);
    if (index < 0) {
      this.groupValue.push(group);
    } else {
      this.groupValue.splice(index, 1);
    }
    const newGroupValue = [];
    newGroupValue.push.apply(newGroupValue, this.groupValue);
    this.groupValue = newGroupValue;
  }

  changeUser(event) {
    const user = event.target.value;
    const index = this.userValue.indexOf(user);
    if (index < 0) {
      this.userValue.push(user);
    } else {
      this.userValue.splice(index, 1);
    }
    const newUserValue = [];
    newUserValue.push.apply(newUserValue, this.userValue);
    this.userValue = newUserValue;
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users;  let i=index">
    <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
            <input type="checkbox" name="customersUserFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="user.name" (change)="changeUser($event)">
                      {{ user.name }}
     </label>&nbsp;
 </ng-container>

<br>

 <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users;  let i=index">
    <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
            <input type="checkbox" name="customersGroupFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="user.group" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
                      {{ user.group }}
     </label>&nbsp;
 </ng-container>

<pre>You select groups {{ userValue | json }} {{ groupValue | json }}</pre>
 <div *ngFor="let user of users | filter2 : 'name' : userValue | filter2 : 'group' : groupValue">
   {{ user.id }} - {{ user.name }}, {{ user.group }}
  </div>
```

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter2'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(singleItem => {
      return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null &&  singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @ConnorsFan the stackblitz is enough. Why don't you code a single pipe that takes an array of filters to apply, then apply the filters with a logical OR, instead of the current implicit AND?

Comment: @YoukouleleY - The stackblitz is a nice addition but does not eliminate the need to include the relevant code in the question, to make it complete and useful for future readers. External links are not considered reliable; the stackblitz could be deleted or reused for other purposes.

Comment: @YoukouleleY can you give me a stackblitz with what you are saying? I tried something like you said but it's not working. I am sorry if I ask too much, but since Monday i've been trying to make this work, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Tenzolinho, if we check john mike g2 what should be expected result

Comment: @Tenzolinho, please provide few possible scenarios and expeced result

Comment: @NagaSaiA if I check `mike`, `john` and `g2` I am expecting to get the user that belongs to `g2`, and that's `mike`.

Answer (score 2):

I forked your StackBlitz, let me know if it helped you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upjdc3

My modifications in the pipe:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], filters:{[key: string]: string}): any[] {
    return items.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      for(let field in filters) {
        if(filters[field].includes(currentValue[field]) && !accumulator.includes(currentValue)) {
          return accumulator.concat([currentValue]);
        }
      }
      return accumulator;
    }, []);
  }
}
```

And in the template :

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | filter2 :  {'name' : userValue, 'group' : groupValue }">
```

Comment: It work's okay..but I don't want to append the value everytime. For example, if I check `mike`, `john` and `g3` it works ok. But if I check `mike`, `john` and `g2`, I want the program to only keep the user that belongs to `g2`, and that's `mike`. I am sorry I didn't mention this at first.